# Logging PHP fatal-errors in CakePHP system

Tags: cakephp, logging, cakephp-2.0, php

I need to log Fatal-errors of my website.

I normally check error.log and debug.log files for CakePHP errors.
But I found out that PHP related fatal errors aren't logged someplace.
It is also discussed [in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cake-php/bPpmO-Vs_rY).

I checked php.ini. IT has following lines:

```
log_errors = On
;error_log = filename
```

I don't have rights to change php.ini. I can ask admin to change this, but it seems like I need to ask him every time I need a change :) I also have concerns about performance. Whether logging errors can decrease performance or not?

So I find out that I can put following two lines inside my script to log errors and change folder or file name when I need.

```
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "/path/to/php-error.log");
```

So I want to know where to put this lines inside my codes? Should I put it inside AppController::beforeFilter ? Or is there a better place/solution in CakePHP 2 configuration?

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can't log fatal errors inside PHP since a fatal error is, well, fatal to the PHP interpreter. Your ini_set method is also potentially flawed since it won't catch any errors up to an including loading the file those lines are inside, so early death still won't be logged appropriately.

Comment: isn't apache logging those errors too?

Comment: If the fatal error happens in any included file (i.e. not the first request file) it should be fairly easy to log using `[set_error_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)`. Parse/Compile errors on the other hand cannot be handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is an old thread.
in the meantime with cake 2.x errors are all logged in productive mode - so also fatal errors.

trigger one and check out your `/tmp/logs/error.log`

but you can easily find that out looking at the core code:
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php#L189

Comment: unfortunately fatal errors aren't logged in error.log. I checked many times that file after seeing fatal errors on browser window.

Comment: are you on the latest 2.x? for it it works anyway - oh, it might be >= 2.2: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-2-migration-guide.html#error-handling - if you cant upgrade you need to use my "register_shutdown_function" function you linked in your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is framework defined configuration settings. You can use the [Error Handling configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/errors.html#error-configuration) class.

Here is [changing fatal error behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/errors.html#changing-fatal-error-behavior) link, that will help you to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

`register_shutdown_function();`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php